# Problem with upload file => 2 GiB Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint

Sorry for my bad language (I use Google translator). Help please understand the problem. There are 2 windows servers 2016 Standart, on one installed DC AD, IIS and SharpePoint 2016. On the other MSSQL 2016. From the client, through sharepoint I connect to the storage in the explorer. I'm uploading a 2 gigabyte file through the explorer to the storeroom. The file is downloaded for a few seconds, then reaches 99% and stands up for a long time. Then there are two kinds of events. Sometimes the file seems to be downloaded, but in the store it is the size of 0 kilobytes and sometimes it gives an error that it does not find the file in the attached repository. Many different configs corrected, the result does not change. In the process monitor (sysinternals) observed what was happening and noticed that the file is first placed in the local temp folder and from there it is transferred to the storage and this transfer occurs 3 times! Why so, until I figured out. Help please with this trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the page [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider adding some code you used to your question. This enables others to answer easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2016's default allowed upload size is 2GB so you are probably hitting the limit. You can increase it to maximum 10 GB. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34128.sharepoint-2016-file-size-limit.aspx

Comment: Limits were removed when the server was first configured.